# Handle click events in a list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, frontend

Here is a [ToDoList](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/todomvc.html) from Vue examples.

I want to add some extra features to this small app, e.g. set date for task. Therefore I'd like to show more operations of the task when I click "...".

[image: click ... then appear delete option]

Below is what I want to avoid, which after clicking another task, the previous click action doesn't be removed:
[image]

I try to add a property for each todo, and bind a click function on the "..." (more). Each time click "more", firstly set "isMoreClick" property of all task to false, then toggle the value of "isMoreClick" of current clicked task:

```
<button class="more"
  @click="isMoreClick(todo)"
  v-show="!todo.isMoreClick">
</button>
<div class="more-opt" v-show="todo.isMoreClick">
  <button class="destroy" @click="removeTodo(todo)"></button>
</div>

...

this.todos.push({
  id: todoStorage.uid++,
  title: value,
  completed: false,
  isMoreClick: false // this is what I added
})

...

isMoreClick (todo) {
  this.todos.forEach(todo => {
    todo.isMoreClick = false
  })
  todo.isMoreClick = !todo.isMoreClick
}
```

I think my approach is a little stupid. Is there any better solution? (set a flag symbol?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say how you're rendering the todo elements. But if you're using a `v-for` loop, one approach could be

```
<ul>
    <li
        v-for="(todo, index) in todos"
        :key="index"
    >
        {{todo.whatever}}
        <button 
            v-if="index !== visibleTodoIndex"
            class="more"
            @click="visibleTodoIndex = index"
        />
        <div 
            v-else
            class="more-opt"
        >
            <button 
                class="destroy" 
                @click="visibleTodoIndex = -1"
            />
        </div>
    </li>
<ul>
```

Then just add `visibleTodoIndex` to the component's `data`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me you need to use a global variable accessible from all todos, not to have a local variable inside each todo and updating it everywhere every time. I recommend using `vuex` store and updating `isMoreClick` value via mutations.